# lxml: Append 'None' or Null value when html tag text content is None

Tags: python, google-app-engine, lxml

Trying to read a html content and extract the last table's content to an array using `lxml`.

Here is my last table:

```
<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><p>T1</p></td>
                <td><p>T2</p></td>
                <td><p>T3</p></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><p>A1</p></td>
                <td><p></p></td>
                <td><p>A3</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

When i run the below code, `eol_table` value is `['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'A1', 'A3']` . Its not showing the `None` or blank value when `<p>` content is blank.

Expected value is `['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'A1', '', 'A3']`. How can i get the result like this ?

Code:

```
eol_html_content =  urlfetch.fetch("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7384181/Test.html").content

import lxml.html as LH
html_root = LH.fromstring(eol_html_content)

eol_table = None
for tbl in html_root.xpath('//table'):
   eol_table = tbl.xpath('.//tr/td/p/text()')

self.response.out.write(eol_table)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root of your problem is, that the `text()` in your xpath is part of test for elements to retreive and as it is None for some `p` elements, it is not retreived.

The solution is to modify xpath to select all `p` elements and then get the `text` from it.

```
import lxml.html as LH

xmlstr = """
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><p>T1</p></td>
            <td><p>T2</p></td>
            <td><p>T3</p></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><p>A1</p></td>
            <td><p></p></td>
            <td><p>A3</p></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
"""

html_root = LH.fromstring(xmlstr)

eol_table = None
for tbl in html_root.xpath('//table'):
     p_elements = tbl.xpath('.//tr/td/p')
     eol_table = [p_elm.text for p_elm in p_elements]

     print eol_table
```

This prints:

```
['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'A1', None, 'A3']
```

Alternative for case, where some  element has no

(this updated request asked by Nijo and he also came with `text_content()` call)

```
xmlstr = """
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><p>T1</p></td>
            <td><p>T2</p></td>
            <td><p>T3</p></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><p>A1</p></td>
            <td><p></p></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
"""
html_root = LH.fromstring(xmlstr)

eol_table = None
for tbl in html_root.xpath('//table'):
    td_elements = tbl.xpath('.//tr/td')
    eol_table = [td_elm.text_content() for td_elm in td_elements]
    print eol_table
```

what prints

```
['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'A1', '', '']
```

As you see, `text_content()` never returns `None` but in `None` cases returns empty string `''`

Comment: if have a `<td>` with no `<p>` tag, how do i add `None` in list for that column?

Comment: @Nijo - to work with `<td>` without `<p>` elements you shall change from `p_elements = tbl.xpath(".//tr/td/p")` to `td_elements = tbl.xpath(".//tr/td")`. Then loop over found `td` elements: if there is no `p` element in it, you return `None`, if there is `p`, return the `text()` of it. As this makes the looping over `td` a bit longer, I would not use list comprehension and use usual `for` loop on found `<td>` elements. Find your way how to get from `<td>` to `<p>` yourself (of ask another question).

Comment: `p_elements = tbl.xpath('.//tr/td')`
`eol_table = [p_elm.text_content() for p_elm in p_elements]` This helped me to solve the issue.

Comment: @Nijo Thanks for `text_content`, I had the feeling there is something like that, but did not have time to complete my check. I added new part to my answer showing this.